# Theme directory printing at top left of website

Tags: wordpress, directory, themes

After I moved servers my theme directory somehow prints at the top left of my page.
I have tried a lot of things but am getting a bit frustrated.
Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this?
When I change theme it disappears, but it also disappears when I clone the site to my local version.

Greetings and thanks for any help.

Comment: you might be missing a file...somewhere.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Try checking log files as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that either a file is missing, or the markup in the line where your theme directory is defined is possibly missing a single quote, double quote, or some other form of syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom theme? Disable it and use a standard `WordPress theme` (like `twentytwelve` or `twentythirteen`).

- If the issues disappears, then issue is related to your theme and you (or the `theme`'s developer) and you'll need to resolve the issue in the `theme`'s code.
- If the problem is not in the theme...

  - If Are you using plugins?
    1 Disable all plugins
    2 re-enable them one by one until the problem appears.
    3 Remember which plugin you last enabled. Then contact the plugin developer and let them know of a potential issue with their plugin.